# What is the original statement of Jung-Abhyankar theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras

I can find many modification of the Jung-Abhyankar theorem. I can even find a new proof of the theorem (by K. Kiyek and J. L. Vicente). But I cannot find the original statement.  Does any one know which paper/book is it in?  Where can I access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original papers are accessible online:

- H. W. E. Jung, [Darstellung der Funktionen eines algebraischen Körpers zweier unabhängigen Veränderlichen x, y in der Umgebung einer Stelle x = a, y = b.](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/index.php?id=resolveppn&PPN=GDZPPN002166585)
  Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik **133**, 289-314 (1908)
- S. S. Abhyankar, [On the ramification of algebraic functions.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372643) Amer. J. Math. 77 (1955), 575–592.

Jung's paper is devoted exactly to this result, whereas Abhyankar's gives a more contextualized explanation (his was an unsuccessful attempt to pass to characteristic $p$); I *think* the version of Abhyankar-Jung in Abhyankar is Theorem 3 (but it might be worth studying the paper carefully).

In Jung's statement, which I reproduce here, the field $K$ is defined as $K=\mathbb{C}(x,y)[z]/(f)$ for some irreducible polynomial $f$ (which is implicitly assumed to involve all three variables).

> Man kann Funktionenpaare $u, v$ des Körpers $K$ bestimmen derart, daß $x$ und $y$ gewönliche Potenzreihen von $u$, $v$ werden, die für $u=v=0$ verschwinden, während alle anderen Funktionen von $K$ entweder gewöhnliche Potenzreihen von $u, v$ werden, oder Quotienten solcher. Eine endliche Anzahl solcher Funtionenpaare und Entwicklungen genügt, die Funktionen von $K$ für die ganze Umgebung von $x=0, y=0$ darzustellen.

My translation:

> It is possible to determine pairs of functions $u, v \in K,$ such that $x$ and $y$ become usual power series in $u, v$, vanishing for $u=v=0$, while every other function in $K$ is either a usual power series in $u,v$ or a quotient of such. A finite number of such pairs and series is enough to represent all functions of $K$ in a neighborhood of $x=0, y=0$.

This seems to be equivalent, in the formulation usual in more recent papers, to the following (I use $\mathbb{C}\{x\}$ to denote convergent power series):

> Let $f\in\mathbb{C}\{x,y\}[z]$ be a monic irreducible Weierstrass polynomial having a discriminant of the form $x^\alpha y^\beta u$, with $\alpha, \beta$ nonnegative integers, and $u\in \mathbb{C}\{x,y\}$ a unit. Then there exist positive integers $n, m$ such that $f$ has all its roots in
>   $\mathbb{C}\{x^{\frac{1}{n}},y^{\frac{1}{m}}\}$.

Abhyankar considers the case of $n$ variables over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.

Comment: K may be not a field.I think that you mean qutient field of K

Comment: Thanks! The notation did not make much sense, really. 

Comment: Abhyankar's approach seems purely formal. Does the result tell us anything about the convergence of the fractional power series?

Comment: Abhyankar's motivation (Zariski's!) was trying to generalize to positive characteristic, so he probably didn't care much for convergence. Jung does care about convergence, and I suppose the series are convergent for more variables too, one should look at modern proofs I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The fractional power series solutions remain convergent in several variables. In fact, if you replace  the ring of convergent power series by any Henselian ring $H$ of power series series satisfying some stability properties, then the fractional power series solution remain in the ring. See for instance http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2559